# C# - Code in form constructor not executed

Tags: c#, winforms

Relatively new to C#; hopefully I'm just overlooking something simple.

I have a form named 'Exercise1' which contains a picture box called 'drawingArea' and a few buttons. The code for the constructor of Exercise1 is as follows:

```
public Exercise1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    paper = drawingArea.CreateGraphics();
    balloon = new Balloon("redBalloon", Color.Red, drawingArea.Width / 2, 
        drawingArea.Height / 2, 30);
    paper.Clear(Color.White);
    balloon.Display(paper);   
}
...
```

'paper' and 'balloon' are created as globals above the constructor for use in the other methods on the form. Both 'paper' and 'balloon' work as initialized in the constructor in the other methods defined on the form.

For whatever reason, the commands

```
paper.Clear(Color.White);
```

and

```
balloon.Display(paper);
```

Which should clear the picture box and show a red ellipse, don't execute (at least visibly). What gives?

**UPDATE:**
Think I'm going to like this website... You guys are quick!
@Nitesh: The constructor for Exercise1 is called from another form. Code is as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int exSelector = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
            switch (exSelector)
            {
                case 1:
                    Exercise1 form1 = new Exercise1();
                    form1.Show();
                    break;
...
```

@Sean Dunford: Yes and yes it is.
@RBarryYoung: Was playing around with that a bit, but had no luck. What command triggers a Form_Load event for Exercise1?

**UPDATE:** This altered code works as expected:

```
public Exercise1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            paper = drawingArea.CreateGraphics();
            drawingArea.BackColor = Color.White;
            drawingArea.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.drawingArea_Paint);
            balloon = new Balloon("redBalloon", Color.Red, drawingArea.Width / 2, drawingArea.Height / 2, 30); 
        }
        private void drawingArea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            balloon.Display(e.Graphics);
        } 
...
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: please post some code from where are you calling the constructor

Comment: Can you show the declaration of Balloon and Paper is this a Static Class etc...?

Comment: @Nitesh It's a constructor... what do you mean?

Comment: They're probably too early in the initialization process.

Comment: Have you tried breakpointing the clear function to see if it's even being called?

Comment: @AndrewBarber I meant from where the object of the class is being created..

Comment: Visual methods generally do not work if they are executed before the Form becomes visible, which is why stuff like this is usually in the Form_Load event.

Comment: You should remove this line paper = drawingArea.CreateGraphics(); from the constructor, it creates Graphics object that is not Disposed. Generally, there is a recommendation that you should dispose all created Graphics objects (at least that was the recommendation found in books few years ago)

Comment: @Nick So I should delete that from my code, and replace all instances of 'paper' with 'drawingArea.CreateGraphics()'?

Comment: No,you should avoid even calling CreateGraphic method. As you have seen in comments and answers,the best way to draw something is to do it in an event handler (like in example I sent) or to override OnPaint method when you are subclassing some Control. Therefore,there is no need to create Graphic object at all,they are available trough EventArguments. Since paper is a reference to Graphic there is no need for it at all. That is not a mistake but not good practice. That`s all. See you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do drawing in the constructor. To do proper drawing, you need to have the form shown on the screen. You can try using the `Shown` event to do your rendering (this may get lost when the form is redrawn, though).

Usually the best way is to set whatever flags you need in the constructor and then use the [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event of the form to do all painting. Later on, when you need to repaint something, set up whatever state needs to be rendered, invalidate your form (this results in a [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event) and then you can repaint the new state.

If you try to do customized drawing (outside your [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event) you'll run the risk of things randomly going blank or your drawing may disapper when you resize/minimize your form.

Comment: This is called immediate mode graphics - every time the form needs to be updated, your application must re-render its output to the form. Here's an article about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You use Graphics in a constructor, that means that you draw on the paper only once, any redraw for whatever reason that happens after constructor will draw the drawingArea in its original way. Try to add PaintEventHandler to drawingArea and then call inside balloon.Display(e.Graphics);

```
    public Exercise1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        balloon = new Balloon("redBalloon", Color.Red, drawingArea.Width / 2, 
        drawingArea.Height / 2, 30);


        drawingArea.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(drawingArea_Paint);
    }

    void drawingArea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        baloon.Display(e.Graphics);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be overriding the forms [`OnPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event handler. In doing so, you are able to get the graphics context which will redraw your paper and balloon areas.